# Function compostion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

let $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$  be the following functions:
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x+1 & \text{ if $x$ is even} \\ 
x-1 & \text{ if $x$ is odd}
\end{array} \right.
$$
$$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x/2 & \text{ if $x$ is even} \\ 
(x-1)/2 & \text{ if $x$ is odd}
\end{array} \right.
$$

Match the following composition with their definitions.
$$
h(x) = g(x)
$$
Is this composition $g \circ g$?

Comment: What four compositions?

Comment: I've made an edit with format but I do not understand what is your question, there is no compositions in the post other than $g \circ g$. If you want to know if the function $h$ given by $h(x)=g(x)$ is $g \circ g$ then the answer is **NO**, $h=g\circ \text{id}=\text{id} \circ g$, where $\text{id}(x)=x$ is the identity map.

Comment: Im sorry, I edited my question. The question offers four options but I wanted to check to see if choice was correct

Comment: Then **NO**! $h \neq g\circ g $, as I told you in my previous comment!

Comment: I read your response after I wrote the reply. Thank you for editing. So the other options are  $g \circ f$,  $f \circ f$,  $f\circ g$. Can you give me some insight of how to approach the problem?

Comment: A direct computation shows that $g\circ f=g$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $h= g \circ f$. To see this, take first $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x$ is an even number, thus there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x=2n$, then
$$
(g \circ f)(x) = (g \circ f)(2n) = g(f(2n))=g(2n+1) = (2n+1-1)/2 = n =g(2n)=g(x)
$$
If we now take $x \in \mathbb{N}$ to be an odd natural number then $x=2n+1$, and hence
$$
(g \circ f)(x) = (g \circ f)(2n+1) = g(f(2n+1))=g(2n) = n= g(2n+1)=g(x)
$$
Since for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we just proved that $(g \circ f)(x) = g(x)$, then indeed $g \circ f = g $.